# Is there a way to permanently set the brightness level

Tags: laptop, battery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make GNOME remember brightness setting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3841/how-to-make-gnome-remember-brightness-setting)

For the sake of long battery life I decrease my laptop's brightness as soon as I log in but when I reboot the laptop. The Brightness goes back to full and I have to decrease it again.
Its really bugging me now.

Is there a way to permanently set the brightness level.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://askubuntu.com/q/3841/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My apologies, I should have looked into it more. 
I found the option of configuring brightness in [Ubuntu tweak](http://ubuntu-tweak.com/downloads/).

the option to control the brightness can be found in '**power Management settings**' under the tab **system** on Ubuntu tweak

Comment: I know that, I changed the title so that no one else bother about answering it. I cant accept my own 'answer' as accepted before 2 days. I think this is good enough reason to satisfy the reason of changing my header.

Comment: @Guarav No need to apologize, remember someone will run into this too, please link to what Ubuntu Tweak is so the next person can benefit!

Answer (score 1):

You could try [acpitool](http://linux.die.net/man/1/acpitool). It might not work on your laptop, but its worth a shot.

for minimum brightness:

```
acpitool -l 0
```

for maximum brightness:

```
acpitool -l 7
```

Now you just need to add that command to your startup script.

**note**: the above command must be [run as root](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3063/how-do-i-run-a-command-as-the-system-administrator-root).