# Permanently set monitor brightness

Tags: kubuntu, kde, brightness

I increase and reduce the LCD brightness on the command line as described here<sup>1</sup>:
**[xrandr --output HDMI-0 --brightness 0.2](https://askubuntu.com/a/149264/1017209)**

**My problem is that my brightness setting is automatically reset after a few seconds.**

My **workaround** is a small Autokey (Python) script ([gist](https://gist.github.com/ba9283269432eeffa346e5b904deeb52)) that permanently sets my setting.
How can it be done better without this little unnecessary extra CPU load?

#### Operating System: Kubuntu 20.04

```
KDE Plasma Version: 5.18.5
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.68.0
Qt Version: 5.12.8
Kernel Version: 5.4.0-52-generic
OS Type: 64-bit
```

---

1: By the way: There is a question with the same name, but it describes a slightly different problem.
[Is there a way to permanently set the brightness level](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10220/is-there-a-way-to-permanently-set-the-brightness-level)

Comment: `xrandr` won't work with Wayland (let alone it doesn't work with some graphics drivers), thus is not the ideal way for a modern Kubuntu system (it has been *sunsetted* by KDE). Sorry I use Lubuntu so can provide the lxqt commands but not appropriate KDE commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That must be due to Redshift/Night Color. Use the command `sudo apt remove redshift`
to uninstall redshift. In case Night Color is enabled, disable it in system settings.

If you are using a laptop, you can control brightness with the function keys, there's no need to use `xrandr`.

If you are using a desktop, you can use Brightness Controller, which is a GUI tool to control brightness, and it can also change the color temperature (it uses `xrandr` in the backend)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:apandada1/brightness-controller
sudo apt update
sudo apt install brightness-controller
```

[image]

*(disclaimer - I am one of the developers of this software)*

You will have to disable Night Color to use Brightness Controller (note that it does not work with Wayland).

Comment: Since the problem is no longer there, at the moment, at almost 8 a.m., I suspect that you are right. I'll test this out tonight.

Comment: Yes, I had "Night Color" activated so that I (my eyes) get tired in the evening and I don't work too long. It is described in the "Night Color" GUI as: "makes the colors on the screen warmer to reduce eye strain" ([imgur](https://i.imgur.com/AKdLdg2.png)).

Comment: @SL5net Check my edited answer. You can disable night color and use an alternative software which can control both brightness and color of the screen

Comment: Found this is a long-known open issue with redshift [open since 2015](https://github.com/jonls/redshift/issues/175). Workarounds for this already exist, but you have to make the settings yourself during the day. they does not change automatically (depending on time / latitude/longitude )

Answer (score 0):

This is a long-known **open** (Nov2020) bug with redshift (bug open since 2015). Described here [githubredshift issues 175](https://github.com/jonls/redshift/issues/175) and something similar here [how-to-use-xrandr-gamma-for-gnome-night-light-like-usage](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1003101/how-to-use-xrandr-gamma-for-gnome-night-light-like-usage).

### Some Workarounds (not yet completely substitute solutions):

most of they does not change automatically depending on day time and recommends detestation of redshift

- WinEunuuchs2Unix writes a collection of bash scripts to adjust [brightness and gamma gradually at dawn and dusk](https://blog.onetwentyseven001.com/more-of-xrandr-or-blue-light-exposure/#.W2ExkRRKjb1)
- Simple AutoKey Script which runs every second (so RedShift does not have to be uninstalled).: [gist](https://gist.github.com/ba9283269432eeffa346e5b904deeb52)
- brightness-controller https://askubuntu.com/a/1290035/1017209