# How do you save the brightness settings?

Tags: 11.10, gnome, settings, brightness

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Desktop doesn't remember brightness settings after a reboot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3841/desktop-doesnt-remember-brightness-settings-after-a-reboot)

It becomes quite annoying to lower brightness each time I boot up my system so, I've been searching how to save current laptop screen brightness in Ubuntu 11.10 for quite some time, sadly, without any luck.

There's no option in System Settings > Power for it nor in compizconfig-settings-manager.

Can someone point me to the right direction?

Comment: This might be useful - http://askubuntu.com/questions/65925/brightness-setting-not-saved-in-ubuntu-11-10

Comment: @Santosh I did it and it somewhat works. The brightness is set to the value I mention in rc.local each time I log on but, after coming back from small idles in which the display dims in order to save energy it jumps back up to 100% or, whenever I try to adjust the brightness using the function keys on my laptop, it jumps to 100% on the first key hit and only after that it is adjustable.