# Brightness setting not saved in Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: 11.10, brightness

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make GNOME remember brightness setting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3841/how-to-make-gnome-remember-brightness-setting)

I have to reconfigure the brightness every time after reboot. is there anyway to make it remember the settings, or other workaround if possiable?