# How do I permanently change the brightness of the screen?

Tags: 11.10, brightness, lenovo

On the previous versions the default screen brightness was perfect for me but on 11.10 the default brightness is killing my eye.

I have changed the brightness like this level

[image]

but after restarting and every login/logout it returns to default 100%.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Desktop doesn't remember brightness settings after a reboot](http://askubuntu.com/questions/3841/desktop-doesnt-remember-brightness-settings-after-a-reboot)

Comment: @Achu - have you looked at the answers in the duplicate question flagged by Jorge? or have you solved the problem some other way. Can you provide some updated information if not I will flag to close the question as a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a bug on `kernel 3.0.0-12-generic` and i report it on [launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/)

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-power-manager/+bug/875061

another report i linked to it:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-control-center/+bug/870805

The suggested solution was to upgrade to `3.1`.  So, I installed `kernel 3.1.0-030100-generic` and the problem fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try Ishans Python script:
http://blog.ishans.info/2011/09/25/set-brightness-automatically-at-the-startup-in-linux/

This stores the current brighness-Information until the next boot.

Answer (score 0):

From Ubuntu 10.04 to 11.10 I can not change my screen brightness. I use an Acer laptop with VGA Intel HD graphic 3000, and I think this is because my laptop (I tried to update BIOS two or three times so I think that make problems)

I must use [xbrightness](http://disjunkt.com/xbrightness/)
to fix my problem. You can try to install this package.

It requires some packages like: xutils-dev, libxxf86vm-dev, libxaw7-dev.
After installation finish. You can change the brightness by run for example:

```
$ xbrightness 50000
```

You can read more on the man page or home site of xbrightness.

You can use this program while waiting for the bug fixed.