# How to save brightness settings?

Tags: 12.04, power-management

After I upgraded my notebook to ubuntu 12.04, I found that I can not save my power settings. Every time I set the screen brightness to 70%, it restored to 100% next time. I can't find a save button on the new power setting panel(I am sorry for I can not post a screenshot right now). Can anyone tell me how to save this setting? Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

if you just wana change and save the screen brightness only, you can use `xbacklight`

```
     sudo apt-get install xbacklight
```

after installing, type command to set the screen brightness easily

```
     xbacklight -set `num`
```

the `num` is percentage of your screen brightness.

### An easier way to set brightness and contrast

```
     sudo setpci -s `00:02.0` F4.B=`XX`
```

to set brightness, `00:02.0` is your VGA device code.`XX` is hexadecimal form 00 to FF

use `lspci` command to find out your VGA device code.

```
     xgamma -gamma `X`
```

to set contrast,`X` from 0 to 1

Comment: Oh, currently I just want to save my screen brightness settings. Thanks, Teifi. :)

Comment: I can`t believe there is no GUI for this. Ubuntu should be linux for human beings. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Beware about using setpci for this. For details see http://askubuntu.com/questions/66751/how-do-i-set-default-display-brightness

Answer (score 19):

1. Check brightness levels by running this command as root:

   ```
   cat /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/max_brightness
   ```

   (my laptop max brightness is 20)
2. Set you screen brightness to minimum and check current level by evoking next command

   ```
   cat /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
   ```

   (my laptop min brightness level is 0;)
3. Edit `/etc/rc.local` and *add before* `exit 0` the following line:

   ```
   echo YOUR_VALUE > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
   ```

From now on this brightness level will be set every time you start your computer.

Comment: The directory with the brightness setting could have a different name. In my case (ThinkPad T540p, Ubuntu 14.04.3) it is: `/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/`.

Comment: Works on startup but not after hibernate or suspend. Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 8):

Personally I prefer starting with the brightness I had the last time I used my computer. Here is how I got that functionality:

First create a file to store your screen brightness between sessions:

> cd /etc/init.d
>
> sudo touch prev_brightness
>
> sudo chmod o+w prev_brightness

Then create a script that stores your current screen brightness when shutting down into the file you created in the previous step:

> sudo touch save_screen_brightness
>
> sudo chmod +x save_screen_brightness
>
> sudo gedit save_screen_brightness

Put this into the file you just opened:

> #!/bin/sh
>
> cat /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness > /etc/init.d/prev_brightness

Now we need to make the script run every time we shut down or reboot the computer:

> sudo ln -s /etc/init.d/save_screen_brightness /etc/rc0.d/K99save_screen_brightness
>
> sudo ln -s /etc/init.d/save_screen_brightness /etc/rc6.d/K99save_screen_brightness

Finally we need to load the value we stored when starting the computer:

> sudo gedit /etc/rc.local

Put this, before exit 0, into the file you just opened:

> cat /etc/init.d/prev_brightness > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness

That's it!

Comment: Thanks, the solution worked like a charm although there is a slight pause before the previous settings are retained.

Answer (score 3):

Using Ubuntu 12.10 the solution Hevilath gave didn't work for me.  No matter what I did with rc.local it wouldn't run.

I tried to add

```
echo 5 > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
```

before the `exit 0` and it was not being called.  I added some logging statements to `/etc/rc.local` and `/etc/init.d/rc.local` and nothing was being run at all.

This should be working because Upstart still runs the older System V scripts at the appropriate times for backwards compatibility.

So I read up on how to write an Upstart script from [here](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/).

I figured since System V is on its way out, I should learn about Upstart.

I wrote a simple script to set the brightness on my two monitors and it works without issue.

Check it out [here](https://github.com/genspire/bin/blob/master/brightness.conf).

All you have to do is copy the file into your /etc/init/ directory using sudo.  It should just work unless the brightness value is being echo'ed to the wrong file in case it is a simple change.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

```
gksudo gedit /usr/local/bin/brightness_changer.py
```

Paste below code,

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import dbus
bus = dbus.SessionBus()
proxy = bus.get_object('org.gnome.SettingsDaemon',
                       '/org/gnome/SettingsDaemon/Power')
iface = dbus.Interface(proxy, dbus_interface='org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Power.Screen')
iface.SetPercentage(70)
```

Save it. Then issue command,

```
sudo chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/brightness_changer.py
```

Open Startup Applications,

[image]

Click Add,

[image]

Give path as `/usr/local/bin/brightness_changer.py` in command and Save it.

Now whenever you login, brightness will be set to `70`.

Comment: I think your program might be better suited for Bash, but I like you answer and I like Python.

Comment: @virpara: I was using your script and it used to work. But it doesn't work anymore with Gnome 3.10. I couldn't find org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Power.Screen with dconf. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a HP all-in-one PC. And I cannot make xbacklight to be executed in rc.local, which the reason needed to be explored.

So I just put the

```
xbacklight -set 0
```

command into StartUp Applications and it helps reduce the screen brightness after login.