# rc.local not executing command

Tags: startup, execute-command, xbacklight

I was trying to make my laptop running Ubuntu 13.10 remember the brightness from the last time and set it automatically on start-up. I was thinking about using `xbacklight` to set the brightness. So, as a test run I added `xbacklight -set 100` inside `/etc/rc.local`. 
But simply it doesn't work. Permission for my rc.local is:

`-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 338 Dec 22 00:08 rc.local`

I also tried adding `sleep 60` considering its a timing issue. But still no luck.

Comment: Here you go:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/145314/how-to-save-brightness-settings

Comment: @phineas xbacklight works fine normally but the problem is with rc.local I think.

Comment: You cannot use xbacklight in rc.local, that is run from root at boot time, and hoping to have it work in a user X session.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put the command into `~/.gnomerc`,
it will be executed on login
(It will be executed on Unity as well).

rc.local is executed before X startup,
so the command is executed but it has no effect.

Comment: But I'll have to wait till I log in. Is there any other way?

Comment: You can try taking a look at `/etc/init/ligthdm.conf`.