# How do I get brightness controls working on a Sony VAIO Fit 15E?

Tags: 14.04, brightness

I have a problem with my brightness setting. When I decrease brightness to 1 and I reboot the computer, it reset to maximum brightness value. I tired to adjust it and decrease it again to 1. Why the setting doesn't save the last brightness setting for me? How can I save the current value and restore it after reboot via programming?

I also tried to add `echo 0 > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness` in `/etc/rc.local` file, but after rebooting, it reset to the maximum again.

My laptop model is `Vaio SVF1521DCXW`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had another folder named `acpi_video0` in this location */sys/class/backlight/*

I added following command at the end but before `exit 0` in `gksu gedit /etc/rc.local` file:

```
 echo 0 > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
 echo 0 > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
```

It worked for me. And now I want to get current brightness and save it into a file to restore it at next restart.

#### How to functionality last adjusted brightness load after next reboot?

**Step 1:** Check brightness levels

Set your brightness to **maximum** and check current level by below command:

```
 cat /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/max_brightness
```

(my laptop max brightness is **100** :)

Now set your brightness to **minimum** and check current level by evoking next command:

```
 cat /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
```

(my laptop min brightness level is **0** :)

**Step 2:** Create a file to store your current brightness:

```
 sudo touch /etc/init.d/prev_brightness
 sudo chmod o+w /etc/init.d/prev_brightness
```

**Step 3:** Create a script that stores your current brightness(the `save_screen_brightness` file) when shutting down into the file `prev_brightness` that you created in the previous step:

```
 sudo touch /etc/init.d/save_current_brightness
 sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/save_screen_brightness
```

Open the `save_screen_brightness` file with your favorite editor app:

```
 gksu gedit /etc/init.d/save_screen_brightness
```

And put this script into it:

```bsh
 #!/bin/sh
 cat /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness > /etc/init.d/prev_brightness
```

Save it and go to next step ;)

**Step 4:** Make the script run every time we shutdown or reboot the computer:

```
 sudo ln -s /etc/init.d/save_current_brightness /etc/rc0.d/K99save_screen_brightness
## Shuttingdown ^^
 sudo ln -s /etc/init.d/save_current_brightness /etc/rc6.d/K99save_screen_brightness
## Rebooting ^^
```

**Step 5:** Load the value we stored when starting the computer:

Add the following line at the end and before `exit 0` into your `/etc/rc.local` file:

```
 cat /etc/init.d/prev_brightness > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
```

That's it ;)

Thanks to [@Hevilath](https://askubuntu.com/users/92011/hevilath)'s [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/191638/283843) and [@user207402](https://askubuntu.com/users/207402/user207402)'s [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/434916/283843) and also [@AiPdimi](https://askubuntu.com/users/295075/aipdimi)'s [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/485647/283843)

Answer (score 2):

On Sony Vaio E15136CN (and most others with an AMD Graphic Card), acpi_video0 is not present. Instead, there is `radeon_bl0` in `/sys/class/backlight`. So the statement to be added to `rc.local` file is

```
echo 60 > /sys/class/backlight/radeon_bl0/brightness
```

Replace 60 with whatever value is suitable to you. My brightness range is 0 to 255 (you can check your maximum brightness in `/sys/class/backlight/radeon_bl0/max_brightness`), so 60 suits me.

None of the answers I came across mentioned the AMD Radeon Graphic Card. So I thought I might add an answer related to it. Also, 
Stéphane Gourichon's answer to [How do I set default display brightness?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66751/how-do-i-set-default-display-brightness) doesn't work on Sony Vaio E15136CN.
So in short, these are the steps to be executed:

Step 1:

```
sudo nano /etc/rc.local
```

Step 2:

```
echo 60 > /sys/class/backlight/radeon_bl0/brightness
```

Step 3:

Restart your system.

Answer (score 1):

make a file like `fixMaxBrightness.sh`

copy all these line to it,
 make it executable by `chmod +x fixMaxBrightness.sh`
and run it by this command `sudo ./fixMaxBrightness.sh`
restart your system.

---

```
#!/bin/bash
#this script are going to get last change screen Brightness
#and put it in /.FixBritness
#this folder is in home directory that the following line make it 
mkdir $HOME/.FixBritness
cd $HOME/.FixBritness

#make two another script that put current brightness in "currntBritness" file, 
#and it must run when system is going down
cat > getBritness.sh <<_EOF_
#!/bin/bash
cat /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/actual_brightness > $HOME/.FixBritness/currntBritness
exit 0
_EOF_

#to get last brightness that saved in "currntBritness" file
#and put it in system brightness file 
cat > putLastBritness.sh <<_EOF_
#!/bin/bash
cat $HOME/.FixBritness/currntBritness > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
exit 0
_EOF_

# create currntBritness file and put zero to defult value
touch currntBritness
echo 0 > currntBritness

chmod 755 getBritness.sh
chmod 755 putLastBritness.sh
#put in /etc/init.d/ because these file will use in /etc/rc1 through rc6
mv getBritness.sh /etc/init.d/
mv putLastBritness.sh /etc/init.d/

#make a symbolic link to  getBritness.sh that get brightness when:
#shutting down
ln -s /etc/init.d/getBritness.sh /etc/rc0.d/S11getBritness.sh
#and restart
ln -s /etc/init.d/getBritness.sh /etc/rc6.d/S11getBritness.sh


#symlink to put last brightness when system start.
ln -s /etc/init.d/putLastBritness.sh /etc/rc1.d/S66putLastBritness.sh
ln -s /etc/init.d/putLastBritness.sh /etc/rc2.d/S66putLastBritness.sh
ln -s /etc/init.d/putLastBritness.sh /etc/rc3.d/S66putLastBritness.sh

exit 0
```