# Ubuntu not starting after running script for brightness

Tags: boot, 14.04, brightness

I was trying to fix brightness on Ubuntu 14.04. So i tried what is mentioned here [How do I set default display brightness?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66751/how-do-i-set-default-display-brightness)
i ran the scripts as mentioned on the terminal.

```
sudo apt-get install xbacklight

sudo bash -c '{
echo "#!/bin/bash"
echo "xbacklight =30"
} > /etc/lightdm/display-setup-script.sh '

sudo chmod a+rx /etc/lightdm/display-setup-script.sh

if 
  grep ^display-setup-script /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf ; 
then 
  echo "Already a display-setup-script. It may already do what you need. Else please adjust manually" ; 
else 
  sudo bash -c "echo display-setup-script=/etc/lightdm/display-setup-script.sh >>/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf" ; 
fi
```

After rebooting the system, the grub is working fine, it shows both Ubuntu and Windows. But after clicking on Ubuntu, it just shows a **black blank screen**. i tried going into recovery mode and updating grub and fixing broken packages, but after that also **Ubuntu dosen't start.** How do i fix this?

Comment: Just press the physical button for brightness increase.

Comment: try https://askubuntu.com/questions/481413/how-do-i-get-brightness-controls-working-on-a-sony-vaio-fit-15e/485647#485647

Answer (score 0):

The command you used is this:

$ echo 5 > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness

Here the number after echo (5 in this case) is the brightness level. If you keep it too low then obviously you won't be able to see anything except black screen. Just increase the brightness of your PC by pressing the physical button for brightness increase and then after you login edit the command to increase the brightness level to maybe 20 or 30 or more, according to your needs. The new command will look like this:

$ echo 30 > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness