# Brightness doesn't decrease in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: laptop, brightness

I've recently installed Ubuntu 14.04 in my Dell Inspiron 5521. I find that brightness is set to a maximum level and Brightness keys doesn't work though they show as if it gets decreased. I searched online and found [a solution](http://itsfoss.com/fix-brightness-ubuntu-1310/.).
But after following the steps, on rebooting, I got just a black screen. Tried brightness keys, yet black screen remains. To revert the changes, I live booted via a usb drive and solved. Now, Ubuntu boots, but still brightness remains maximum. Hope I'll get to solve this.

Comment: try this `xbacklight -set 40`

Comment: possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/145314/how-to-save-brightness-settings

Comment: Above link `user207402` solution worked in my case

Answer (score 0):

Do

```
echo 500 >/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
```