# Screen brightness is always full

Tags: 13.04, brightness

The screen brightness of my laptop is always full when I log in Ubuntu. When I set it low and restarts its again on its maximum. I want it to remember my last choice. How to do this?

Comment: possible duplication of http://askubuntu.com/questions/151651/brightness-is-reset-to-maximum-on-every-restart

Comment: user207402's solution here worked for me http://askubuntu.com/questions/145314/how-to-save-brightness-settings