# Brightness stuck on maximum

Tags: dual-boot, keyboard, brightness

I am using HP Pavilion g6 laptop. It is dual-boot. I have installed Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04 LTS edition.

Keyboard keys are working perfectly fine for increasing and decreasing brightness in Windows 7. But it is stuck on maximum brightness in Ubuntu 12.04. Keyboard keys are not working in Ubuntu. When I try to decrease brightness through keyboard, it stuck on some level and can't be decreased more than that. Brightness is too high.

Answer (score 1):

Answer copied from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66751/how-do-i-set-default-display-brightness)

```
 $ chmod o+w /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
```

Brightness levels are running from 0 - 9.

```
 $ echo 5 > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
```

Comment: `chmod: cannot access '/sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness': No such file or directory`