# Is it possible to run a command before log in screen?

Tags: xbacklight

How can I run:

```
xbacklight -set 0
```

before login screen?

Comment: I am not sure since I am not at home right now, so no ubuntu to test it on,but have a look here, is this what you are looking for?

    gksu gedit /boot/grub/menu.lst

Answer (score 1):

For this you can use the file `/etc/rc.local`. Insert your command to this file before `exit 0` and anytime you start your system the command is executed. Please ensure that he file is also executable.

Comment: I'm experimenting with backlight settings right now and found that since upstart runs asynchronously you can't be 100% sure that everything is initialized the moment `/etc/rc.local` runs. So you might need to add `sleep 10`, or that with a different number, to be sure that the display is ready to take the command.

Answer (score 0):

From your question, it appears you want to set screen brightness on startup. With current architecture (Xorg, not Mir or Wayland) you can do it like written on: [How do I set default display brightness?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66751/how-do-i-set-default-display-brightness/232668#232668)