# Keyboard Backligth is set to Maximum in every reboot

Tags: keyboard, brightness

At every reboot my screen backlight and my keyboard backlight were set up to maximum level on every reboot.

Reading this article:

[How do I set default display brightness?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66751/how-do-i-set-default-display-brightness)

i've solved the problem with my screen backligth running the script mentioned. But i still having problem with my keyboard backlight.

I've already modified with `gksudo /etc/rc.local`, writing on it:

```
echo 0 > /sys/class/leds/asus\:\:kbd_backlight/brightness
```

and also tryed:

```
echo '0' > /sys/class/leds/asus\:\:kbd_backlight/brightness
```

But when I restart the system the keyboardk backlight is set to max again.

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Semantically there is no difference between those lines, `0` and `'0'` are both passed as `0` to `echo` by the shell. Does this line have the desired effect if called on the command line (as superuser)?

Comment: When I edit `/etc/rc.local` and make `gksudo` it has effect. But when i reboot my keyboard backlight is at maximum again.

Comment: For me you solution works. Tested on U14.04 Asus ROG G73SW