# How to set bright at maximum permanently (I've already got a solution, do anyone have a better one?)

Tags: 14.04, brightness

I have to reinstall ubuntu in my Samsung N210 laptop, and now it won't let me set the brightness by hand. This seems to be something related to my BIOS but after looking for it, there's no new release on Samsung.

I've search all over the web, and found that the only thing to solve this is to manually set it this way:

```
sudo setpci -s 00:02.0 f4.b=ff
```

After that the bright is at maximum.

Now, this is my father's pc, and the only way he can read with it, is with the brightness set on maximum. With this solution, I need to manually type it every single time I turn on the pc.

**I wanted to make those changes permanent**, and the only thing that worked was [this solution](http://www.cebuntu.com/how-to/how-set-brightness-on-startup-ubuntu-12-04/). (I even tried [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66751/how-do-i-set-default-display-brightness)) that even says that the solution that actually worked in my case, is not safe enough.

I just would like to know if there's any new solution to this, or maybe some workaround, because it seems that every time I need to reinstall ubuntu I'm going to bump into this (I mean, I have this issue since 12.x version, and **this isn't solved in new versions**).

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Best solution is to purchase a Linux compatible video card. If you need assistance, please identify your hardware and post what you have done or what configuration changes you have made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the command `sudo setpci -s 00:02.0 f4.b=ff` to the end of `/etc/rc.local`

This will force the command to run at every startup.