# require help regarding brightness adjustment

Tags: brightness

i adjust the brightness to a lower level after logging in but this goes back to full after restarting. is there a way to stop this from happening?i am new to ubuntu and did a clean istall of ubuntu 14.10 on dell n5010(2012 model)

Comment: The best explanation I found was by dhanvi in this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66751/how-do-i-set-default-display-brightness).

Comment: If it solves your problem up vote dhanvi's answer.

Comment: dont have enough reputation..sorry

Answer (score 0):

Go to your Power Manager:
(In my case with Lubuntu I would go here but it may be different for you)
*Menu > Preferences > Power Manager*

See if there is an option that specifies startup brightness, or just plain brightness. I do not see these since I am using a Dell Dimension E510 desktop, but you may be able to see them.

If that doesn't work your screen hardware may be defaulted to resetting the brightness level on reboot, and I don't think there is any way to change that setting.

Comment: there is no such option in power manager..

Comment: @SaikatPal Your screen hardware may be defaulted to resetting the brightness level on reboot, and I don't think there is any way to change that setting. For as much as I know at least.