# Unable to start ubuntu after display config change

Tags: display, startup, restart

My laptop brightness is getting reset after waking from sleep.
I applied the [solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/232668/283721) found.

I have created display-setup-script.sh script as suggested.
I have added the code in step 4 in the answer to /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf file.

When I restarted, I am getting display setting error and can't get to login screen.

Is there anyway I can fix this without OS re-install?
I am thinking of using startup or try ubuntu option, is it possible?

Edit: actual error I am getting is "the system is running in low graphics mode". Your screen, graphics card, and input device settings could not be detected correctly. You will need to configure yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you problem its triggered from the script you used in the solution you have found.
Delete that script and start over. Be sure to have Xorg as default display server.

Comment: Can reach virtual terminal, but unable to login due to wrong username. Is there anyway to find existing users probably by running ubuntu from pendrive?

Comment: to reset username and password look here https://askubuntu.com/a/24024/752939

Comment: to guess your username you can try to boot in recovery mode then at the prompt in the terminal try: ls /home ...look at the list, there will be a folder named with your username

Comment: Got my username back. Username is case-sensitive. I can login now. I have used the above command but still facing the issue.

Comment: The britghtness solution you pointed out its for X. Wich ubuntu release are you using???. If like me you are using the 17.10 remember that the default display server its wayland and not Xorg...

Comment: Using 16.04 lts

Comment: I have deleted the executavke file added as mentioned in the answer I followed before. I thing you are asking me change the display manager (not server). I ran sudo dpkg-reconfigure xorg. Didn't get any results, just got new line. But when I tried sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm, I got error in two lines. Insserv: warning : script is corrupt or in valid: /etc/init.d/../rc0.d/k99fixbrightness. Other line just differs at rc6.d/... How to fix this now? Please help. I am able to access console and run commands. Seems like it's not getting connected to internet. Need help with that as well.

Comment: The first warning its related to brightness... maybe its a file made from the executable? Look if deleting that file do something. To be sure to not harm the system make a copy of that files. After deleting that files try to reconfigure. Before troubleshot for internet first fix lightdm.