# 18.04 Cannot change laptop screen brightness

Tags: drivers, nvidia, laptop, brightness, intel

I'm using a Lenovo Y740 laptop (with an RTX 2060 video adapter) with Ubuntu 18.04.4 dual boot with windows 10 installed. The screen brightness is always at max brighness and I'm unable to change it.

I already tried 3-4 solutions provided across the internet but fails to fix the problem. I hope anyone read this and help me.

1. default kernel version is 5.3.0-40-generic (some source says upgrading the kernel will help, i have not tried this yet)
2. nvidia driver 440.59 (i know its rather new but dunno if this the problem, should i downgrade it ?)
3. when i run this command ls /sys/class/backlight/ it shows intel-backlight.
4. currently i can change screen brightness using brightness controller app but i prefer fixing the system (if any problem exist possible).

5.editing grub and adding conf file for intel is not working.

Some fix i already tried :

[this](https://itsfoss.com/fix-brightness-ubuntu-1310/)

[this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1034305/brightness-problem-ubuntu-18-04-lts)

[this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/762764/cant-change-brightness-since-ubuntu-16-04-lts)

Comment: Would you please be specific about what you found and tried? Otherwise, we're certain to ask you to do those things again. Checking in your browser history will show the URLs you visited for the other things you tried. Please click [edit] and add those to your original question; please do not use Add Comment.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I found to fix this problem was by changing the display manager which you can read about [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/829108/what-is-gdm3-kdm-lightdm-how-to-install-and-remove-them). Fair warning, this has unintended consequences because it will change your login screen and other things as well. Sometimes the cure is worse than the dissease. I would advise against this, but I also understand the need to want to fix the brightness issue without having to do it manually every time you boot. Try to switch to lightdm display manger and follow the instructions [here](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/12/how-to-change-default-display-manager.html). Than follow the instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66751/how-do-i-set-default-display-brightness/232668) to use `xbacklight` with a script to change the brightness settings. Next time you reboot, the script should change the brightness on your laptop. Some of the instructions might be dated so you may need to adjust them. I hope that helps, good luck.