# Set the default brightness level in Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: 11.10, gnome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Desktop doesn't remember brightness settings after a reboot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3841/desktop-doesnt-remember-brightness-settings-after-a-reboot)

In 11.10 the way to set the brightness has changed. how can I set my default brightness because my laptop starts all the way down when I log in currently?