# Brightness control in ubuntu 11.10

Tags: 11.10, unity, brightness

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make GNOME remember brightness setting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3841/how-to-make-gnome-remember-brightness-setting)

The brightness control default setting is set to maximum in system settings > Screen. Every time I open my laptop i have to adjust the brightness levels manually. Is there a way to change the default level setting ???

Answer (score 0):

Try installing Jupiter, it has different modes like "power-saving mode", "maximum performance mode" etc. When you connected to power card it'll automatically switches to max performance mode and your brightness is set to full and when you are on battery your brightness would be as you set. It has the capacity to remember your preference so when you log in back you can see your preferred brightness level.

I had the same problem after installing Jupiter the problem is resolved. Hope this resolves yours too.

Thank you.

Comment: Thank U for Jupiter, but it is not controlling my LCD brightness,however i can easily control my power requirements from it. It gives options for screen resolutions, orientations and internal or external displays only not anything about screen brightness. Can u please help any further ???