# Hp Pavilion DV5 doesn't remember brightness settings across reboots

Tags: 11.10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Desktop doesn't remember brightness settings after a reboot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3841/desktop-doesnt-remember-brightness-settings-after-a-reboot)

My problem is with ubuntu 11.10 in my notebook hp pavilion dv5 with a graphic intel(R) hd graphics. When I start ubuntu my screen is without brightness, I can increase it with my control buttons, but when I restart I don't have brightness again.

Answer (score 0):

open up the system settings and goto ----> SCREENS then set the brightness level
hope this will help

Comment: sorry for answer late, but this don't fix my problem, because when i turn off or restart my notebook, it has a black screen again (without bright), also ubuntu doesn't recognize my graphic card (intel HD (R) graphics), please i need your help beacuse i like ubuntu and i would like have it in my laptop (HP dv5 2045la) (3GB RAM) (500 GB DISK)