# Few problems on Dell xps 15 L502 (screen brightness, bluetooth, wi-fi power management problems)

Tags: 11.10, dell, brightness, intel-wireless, xps

I am running ubuntu 11.10 32bit in my dell xps L502. Working well except for a few problems.

1. Blue tooth always turned on reboot,I would like to turn it off always.
2. Screen brightness is not saved. Every time I reboot, the screen goes back to full brightness.How to save that?
3. And the most important problem is internet speed through wi-fi is really very slow when operating on battery.the card is intel centrino Advanced-N 1030 with integrated bluetooth.

Any help will be appriciated... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the general format here is one question at a time.

Your first 2 questions are duplicates

1. [How can I deactivate Bluetooth on system startup?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67758/deactivate-bluetooth-on-startup)
2. [Desktop doesn't remember brightness settings after a reboot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3841/desktop-doesnt-remember-brightness-settings-after-a-reboot)

the third question is, as far as I can tell, a bug

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/821034