# How do i make screen dimming work in ubuntu 12.04 (beta 2)

Tags: 12.04, screen, brightness

I recently installed Ubuntu 12.04 (beta 2) on my HP mini 110-4117, but I cant control screen brightness.
The <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> , <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd> keys don't work. System Settings > Brightness and Lock doesn't provide any means of controlling screen brightness.

How can this be fixed? Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Here is what worked for me.
I got the solution from the folowing links. Check them out or read the summary below.

http://linuxon1001p.blogspot.com/2010/03/fixing-brightness-controls.html

[Desktop doesn't remember brightness settings after a reboot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3841/desktop-doesnt-remember-brightness-settings-after-a-reboot)

Summary:

1. Edit your /etc/default/grub file:

   *sudo gedit /etc/default/grub*
2. Add the options "acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor" to the GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT line. It should look like this:

   *GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor"*

   original line was:

   *GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"*
3. Update grub configuration!!!! - do not forget to do this, the configuration change will not be set up if you don't run the next command:

   *sudo update-grub*

This worked for me after trying a lot of other solutions.
I have a HP dv7-6090ef with hybrid graphics Intel/AMD.

Have fun using Ubuntu!

Comment: Thanks! This solved the problem on my hp g7-1310us after 6 months with screen brightness at full blast.

Answer (score 0):

With Ubuntu 14.04, Acer E1-572, this works:
Create a file /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf and put in it:

```
Section "Device"
Identifier "card0"
Driver "intel"
Option "Backlight" "intel_backlight"
BusID "PCI:0:2:0"
EndSection
```

Comment: The question is obviously about a HP not an Acer device. The important missing info that could make this answer relevant is the chipset model of the two.