# Can't login to GUI, only to tty1-6, /bin is not included in the PATH environment

Tags: grub2, bash, login

I was trying to make the brightness controls work after I had made a clean reinstall of Ubuntu 12.04 on my Gateway computer, based on [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/123604/how-do-i-make-screen-dimming-work-in-ubuntu-12-04-beta-2), and proceeded to restart because I also had a few updates to be done.

Next thing I know, I can't login into the desktop GUI, it flashes a black screen, and gets me back to the login screen.

I then opened up tty6 and logged in with my user and password. I logged in OK, but then immediately this came up:

```
-bash: groups: commmand not found
Command 'uname' is available in '/bin/uname'
```

The command could not be located because `/bin` is not located in the PATH environment variable:

```
uname: command not found
-bash: [: =: unary operator expected
....
```

Several more lines like that and then the command line.

Please help! Maybe I mistyped something when editing the grub file. How would I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Log in on a `tty1` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>) and run these commands:

```
export PATH="/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:$PATH"
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /home/$USER/
```

You can replace $USER with your actual username.

Now, try logging in again.