# Screen dimming doesn't work (Ubuntu 14.04 LTS)

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, screen, brightness

I have an Asus laptop (G53SW), on which I installed Ubuntu 12.04 (because I had it laying around) which upgraded itself to 14.04LTS.

For the most part it works well but the one annoying issue is that I can't dim the screen at all. Moving the slider or toggling the checkbox does nothing at all.

I have found [this previous question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/123604/how-do-i-make-screen-dimming-work-in-ubuntu-12-04-beta-2) and tried the solution involving editing the grub file but that did not help as after making the change and running `sudo update-grub` the slider still had no effect.

I also found [this page](http://itsfoss.com/fix-brightness-ubuntu-1310/) but not only did I not have the "Graphics" section mentionned in the post, when I ran: `ls /sys/class/backlight` what I got back was `acpi_video0  acpi_video1`, also the post seems to mention this only works for integrated video cards but my laptop has a GTX 460M (for which I'm fairly certain I installed the drivers).

How do I go about restoring the screen dimming functionality?

Comment: Check to make sure the NVIDIA drivers are installed by searching `Additional Drivers` in Unity Dash. If it's using the open-source driver, select one of the proprietary options.

Comment: @Zacharee1 I just switched from `NVIDIA legacy binary driver - version 304.125 from nvidia-304 (proprietary)` to `NVIDIA binary driver - version 331.113 from nvidia-331 (proprietary, tested)`, no change so far (but I haven't rebooted yet)

Comment: Reboot. The drivers won't be applied until you do so.

Comment: @Zacharee1 It works now! :D Great success!

Comment: Good! I'm going to add it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an outdated or incompatible proprietary driver for your card. Open the `Additional Drivers` program and check for new drivers. Select the newest one, apply and reboot.