# Laptop Brightness indicator

Tags: unity, indicator, brightness

I have developed a brightness indicator for unity in python. I change the brightness using the following system call:

```
echo 4 > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness  [value = 0 to 9]
```

Problem is this command needs root access. Because of brightness file's permission:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 2012-04-23 17:36 /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
```

So i just change the file's permission to 775. It worked. But after reboot the file's permission change again. Now it can not be done because permission denied. How can i do this without root permission?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you can do is change the permissions in some sort of startup script, such as /etc/rc.local.

Comment: It's a way but looking for better solution. thanks for reply

Comment: this answer has a sample rc.local script: http://askubuntu.com/questions/3841/desktop-doesnt-remember-brightness-settings-after-a-reboot/68143#68143

Comment: Pretty sure sysfs stuff's permissions are not persistent so there's not really any better way to do it.