# Why does Ubuntu reset brightness settings at the loading screen?

Tags: laptop, brightness, backlight, dell-studio-xps-16

Since I first installed Ubuntu 11.10, I noticed that volume and screen brightness get reset every time Ubuntu starts.

Why is this so? And what ways are there to keep brightness and volume levels after rebooting?

I have found some scripts that change the screen-brightness at login. But this is not a good solution since

- login is slower because it seems to wait until the screen brightness is at the level specified by the script. After entering the password I see the screen brightness go down gradually. Only after this is complete (~1 or 2 seconds) does the background disappear and Unity come up.
- The screenbrightness is not remembered but instead redefined at login. So it gets remembered for the first part of the boot, then set to MAX and then again re-set to normal value by the script. My boot process  is as follows:
  desired brightness: **2** (13,33%) / Max brightness: 15 (100%)

  1. Bios / brightness: OK
  2. GRUB (violet background color, white text) / brightness: OK
  3. Ubuntu loading screen with the dots / brightness: MAX (win7 loads with OK-brightness)
  4. User Login / brightness: MAX
  5. Unity starts / brightness: OK
- It seems to be more like a temporary patch than a actual solution.

**I'm looking for solutions that set the desired brightness permanently and consistently throughout the whole boot-process**

After updating to 12.04 the behavior is the same.

I tried

- `setpci -s 02:00.0 F4.B=XX`
  The value of F4.B is always '0' regardless of what value I try to set it to (tried 0, ff, f, 5, etc)
- The solution in this answer does not have any noticeable effect: [Desktop doesn't remember brightness settings after a reboot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3841/desktop-doesnt-remember-brightness-settings-after-a-reboot)
  The variables at `/sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/` get changed if I use <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>UP</kbd> and <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>DOWN</kbd>

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Did you found the answer to this question. I am getting the same problem please help.

Comment: @MurtazaMunshi Unfortunately not. I still have the same issue.

Comment: Damn....Why isn't anyone helping us over here.

Answer (score 2):

With this guide you can save your brightness level on reboot/shutdown and bring it back after system startup. This does not affect system boot up time.

---

Make a text file in your home directory (or wherever else) to save the brightness level in it. Open up terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, then enter the following command:

```
sudo gedit /home/brightness
```

Save and exit gedit. Just let it be empty. Then type this command in terminal:

```
sudo gedit /etc/rc0.d/K99FixBrightness
```

And copy paste the following bash script into it:

```
#!/bin/bash
brightness=`cat /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness`
echo $brightness > /home/brightness
exit 0
```

Then make it executable by entering: `sudo chmod 644 /etc/rc0.d/K99FixBrightness` in terminal.
Rpeat above steps with rc6.d directory:

```
sudo gedit /etc/rc6.d/K99FixBrightness
```

Just so:

```
#!/bin/bash
brightness=`cat /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness`
echo $brightness > /home/brightness
exit 0
```

Then make it executable by entering: `sudo chmod 644 /etc/rc6.d/K99FixBrightness` in terminal.
Until now we set up the brightness level to be saved in /home/brightness before shutdown and reboot. One step to go! Enter the following command in terminal:

```
sudo gedit /etc/rc.local
```

Add this before the last line "exit 0":

```
brightness=`cat /home/brightness`
echo $brightness > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
```

Save and exit gedit. Now with system startup the last brightness level will be loaded!

### Done! :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the following?

Open Terminal (Press Ctrl+Alt+T) and type:

```
sudo gedit /etc/rc.local
```

Add this before the last line "exit 0":

```
echo 4 > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
```

Comment: I edited /etc/rc.local but it has no effect ... I did a few reboots to  make sure. The value of /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness is always 15 after reboot.

Comment: Have you other folders in `/sys/class/backlight/` besides `acpi_video0` ? For example, I've got `/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness` too, and I would add also `echo 4 > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness` to `/etc/rc.local`

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to look into this! I have just that one acpi_video0 folder nothing else. It has a litlle black arrow, though as if it were a shortcut?

Comment: Yes, it's a symlink. If you want to know the original folder, just type `ls -la /sys/class/backlight/`, but this won't help much.

Answer (score 0):

This method will not slow down anything.
Press Ctrl+Alt+t for openeing terminal then use -

```
cat /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/max_brightness
```

it will give you the maximum brightness value, to change it for after booting open-

```
sudo gedit /etc/rc.local
```

and add the line shown below before exit , look at the screenshort I have attached-

```
echo 0 > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
```

Change 0 to the value you want in the start as got from previous command output.

as shown here-[image: here changing]

Now just save it and restart. Hope it helped you.