# Blank Screen after update to 13.04

Tags: graphics, dell, intel, xps

I have a Dell XPS 12 with Intel Graphics. After update to 13.04 my screen stays  dark after boot. When I attach an external monitor it works. But it takes several tries to swicht on the internal display of the notebook.

Can anybody help?

Comment: By tries do you mean you reboots? [This](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it) might help, although I don't think it answers your question directly.

Answer (score 1):

Try brighten up the display with <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>. It seems that the backlight is set to 0 during boot.

Comment: What if I don't have a Fn key on keyboard?

Comment: full solutions is to edit /etc/default/grub and add "acpi_osi=linux acpi_backlight=vendor" so it looks like this:

Comment: sorry, pressing Enter sent the comment

Comment: ... so it looks like this:
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi=linux acpi_backlight=vendor"

save file and update grub.conf with:
sudo update-grub

reboot - should work now

Comment: Uwe, when I try your boot params my boot fails. Other suggestions? Note the Fn+F5 works.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [this cool answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/153518/172945), I found another way to automatically set the screen brightness to a decent level at startup:

In /etc/rc.local, before "exit 0", write the following line:

```
echo 50 > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
```

50 was my personal preference, you can set it to any value from 0 (blank) to 100 (highest)