# Keyboard light and screen brightness at 100% after startup

Tags: keyboard, screen, backlight

After every restart the default screen and keyboard light is at 100% and it is quite annoying. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Nobody knows? :D

Comment: Please include information about your distribution, hardware including graphics card, and the driver you are currently using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me. I'm using a Macbook Pro (late 2013).

Under **`/etc/rc.local`** , add the following lines (before "exit 0")

```
echo X > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
echo Y > /sys/class/leds/smc::kbd_backlight/brightness
```

This will run at startup, so it will be your "Default" values. The first line sets the screen brightness and the second the keyboard backlight brightness. Change X and Y to the values you wish (on my Macbook, X goes from 0 to 100 and Y goes from 0 to 255).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the keyboard light, but the screen brightness problem is probably a duplicate of this question: [Desktop doesn't remember brightness settings after a reboot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3841/desktop-doesnt-remember-brightness-settings-after-a-reboot) Maybe you'll find something there to help you. This is a very well-known bug that affects many computers.