# Problem with keyboard back-light on Ubuntu Mate 16.04 on ThinkPad T450s

Tags: 16.04, thinkpad, mate, ubuntu-mate, keyboard-backlight

I'm using Ubuntu Mate 16.04 with ThinkPad T450s.

When I login into Ubuntu, keyboard back-light is on, then I turn it off, then after spending **idle time** when I touch to any key, keyboard back-light turn on again!

What should I do for disable it?

---

[**UPDATE**]

I found the `keyboard-backlight` brightness file path that toggles with three mode:

- `0` is off
- `1` is low light
- `2` is high light

I set the brightness to `0` in `rc.local` as following, but it not worked:

I put the following line before `exit 0` in `/etc/rc.local`:

- `echo 0 > /sys/class/leds/tpacpi:\:\kbd_backlight/brightness`

---

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [this may help you](https://askubuntu.com/a/504696/260379)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From 
https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/keyboard-light-keeps-turning-on-after-login-and-or-unlock/6914/12
I got the right direction for the solution (similar problem with Ubuntu Mate 18.10 on a ThinkPad T480s).

I edited */etc/dbus-1/system.d/org.freedesktop.UPower.conf* (with `sudoedit`) and changed the `allow` in the lines

```
<allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.UPower"
       send_interface="org.freedesktop.UPower.KbdBacklight"/>
```

to a `deny` so after editing the lines look like this:

```
<deny send_destination="org.freedesktop.UPower"
      send_interface="org.freedesktop.UPower.KbdBacklight"/>
```

No service restart or reload necessary, works directly after changing the file. Manual switching of the keyboard backlight with the hotkey (<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>).

Comment: Thanks, it works. +1