# Make xconf configuration permanent

Tags: xorg, brightness

I edited the `xconf` file, and added this line to device section:

```
Enable brightness control=1
```

Now I am able to adjust brightness, but after every restart the brightness setting change back to 100%.

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Desktop doesn't remember brightness settings after a reboot](http://askubuntu.com/questions/3841/desktop-doesnt-remember-brightness-settings-after-a-reboot)

Comment: I think the second answer of that question might work for you, as it is not only for gnome.

Comment: This is normal, the brightness is always going back to 100%.

Comment: try this https://askubuntu.com/questions/481413/how-do-i-get-brightness-controls-working-on-a-sony-vaio-fit-15e

Comment: What is your card model?

Answer (score 8):

To [adjust brightness in xubuntu or ubuntu](http://namhuy.net/528/adjust-brightness-in-xubuntu.html)
Open a terminal window, and execute this command to edit /etc/rc.local:

```
sudo nano /etc/rc.local
```

Add this before the last line “exit 0″:

```
echo xx > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
```

Where number `xx` is the value of your screen brightness of your choice.

The maximum value for brightness can be found with:

```
cat /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/max_brightness
```

Comment: for others newbie(like me): use ctrl+insert to paste the text from clipboard in nano

Comment: How do you save it afterwards and exit?

Comment: Laptop with Intel card, path is: $ cat /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness

Answer (score 3):

Fix brightness control issue with Intel card in Ubuntu:(check which card is there:settings/details/graphics)

Open a terminal and create the following configuration file, if it does not exist:

touch /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf

Now we need to edit this file. You can use any editor be it a terminal one or graphical.

sudo gedit /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf

Add the following lines to this file:

```
Section "Device"
        Identifier  "card0"
        Driver      "intel"
        Option      "Backlight"  "intel_backlight"
        BusID       "PCI:0:2:0"

EndSection
```

Save it. Log out and log in back. The brightness control should be working through function keys now:

Comment: This made my display driver to crash on 14.04

Comment: Mine too! this does not work and I wasn't able to get my ubuntu up and running after a reboot. Had to re-install.

Comment: Worked for me with Ubuntu 15.04.

Answer (score 2):

create a file in /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/80-backlight.conf and include following in the file.

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier "Intel Graphics"
    Driver "intel"
    Option "AccelMethod" "sna"
    Option "Backlight" "intel_backlight" # use your backlight that works here
    BusID "PCI:0:2:0"
EndSection
```

Answer (score 2):

In `/etc/default/grub` make sure you have `acpi_backlight=vendor` in `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`.

Here is mine:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"
```

Then run `update-grub` and reboot.

Fixed it for me, HP ProBook w/ Intel Grpahics card, fresh 14.04 Desktop install.

Comment: Thx mate. I tried what not. works like charm. Do not forget to ```reboot```

Answer (score 2):

Type this command in Terminal:

```
xrandr --output LVDS-0 --brightness 0.5
```

0.5 is used to decreased to adjust screen Brighness.

Should work Perfectly.

if not

```
xrandr --output LVDS1 --brightness 0.5
```

will do the job

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the screen brightness in Ubuntu

(I can’t change it using the keyboard shortcuts or the Ubuntu Power Management menu),

open a terminal and execute the following:

> sudo setpci -s 00:02.0 F4.B=xx

Where xx is the desired brightness in hex ranging from 0 (brightest) to FF (no brightness at all). I usually change it to E0 when working on battery.