# Screen brightness isn't taking effect on a Lenovo Z570

Tags: nvidia, xorg, brightness

My Lenovo Z570 has two GPU's, nVidia and Intell. Brightness control has no effect what so ever over the screen brightness, and because I've had some major issues in the past when I was trying to fiddle with nVidia drivers and settings, and I wanna be cautious now. I haven't find similar questions referring 14.04 LTS with similar configuration as mine.

I've read that it could be fixed by adding/changing content in `xorg.conf` but when I run

```
sudo gedit /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

the file comes out to be absolutely empty. What do I need to do, what do I need to add to it and not get my laptop screwed with a black screen again?

Comment: this solved my problem : http://askubuntu.com/a/450690/313731

Comment: What is the model of your card?

Comment: nVidia 525M and Intell Integrated HD Graphics 3000

Comment: The solution of @SPRBRN worked on my Lenovo Thinkpad X250 with Intel Graphics and Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 19):

For those of you having this problem with an Intel card, look at [this fix](http://itsfoss.com/fix-brightness-ubuntu-1310/):

You can see whether you use an Intel card with the following command. If you see "intel_backlight", you probably have an Intel card.

```
ls /sys/class/backlight/
```

If so, execute the following command:

```
sudo touch /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf
```

You may check first if that file exists, but touching it won't do any harm. Then edit the file:

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf
```

Insert the following code:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier  "card0"
    Driver      "intel"
    Option      "Backlight"  "intel_backlight"
    BusID       "PCI:0:2:0"
EndSection
```

Save the file, log out, log back in. This worked for me on Ubuntu 14.04, and it should work on 13.10 as well.

[Credits to It's FOSS](http://itsfoss.com/fix-brightness-ubuntu-1310/)

Comment: Here's what I got after doing that:
`(gedit:3465): Gtk-WARNING **: Calling Inhibit failed: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files`
I do have a secondary Intel GPU.

Comment: @SPRBRN: Worked for me. Vostro 1500, just installed Intel driver (to prevent crashes) - boom, 0% backlight == very dim screen. I confirmed with the intel_backlight directory, there was 'actual_brightness' (or some such) in there that had a value of 00.  Once I installed your fix, it jumped way up (256,512 or so).  Thanks for sharing!

Comment: If it happens that you see `intel_backlight`, you change/add `20-intel.conf` but the system will not boot to graphics, you can delete the file in recovery mode (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode).

Comment: This worked for me with Xubuntu 14.10 on a ThinkPad T520 (the problem only occurred after I set up Bumblebee), but for some reason it made Xfce's [Whisker Menu](http://gottcode.org/xfce4-whiskermenu-plugin/) stop working. I ended up just removing the Whisker Menu panel item, but it would be nice to have a fix for that as well.

Comment: Your solution worked on my Lenovo Thinkpad X250 with Intel Graphics and Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 12):

This worked for my Lenovo T530 with Nvidia/Intel...

Note. My BIOS graphics settings were changed from Nvidia Optimus to Discrete Graphics (this was so I can drive a 4K external monitor from the Display Port). Also no need to have the file /etc/X11/xorg.conf on your system. The following assumes you are running the Nvidia driver and have access to the NVIDIA X Server Settings app in Unity.

First, bring up the text editor and I'll show you how to add the right contents to this file for your graphics card.

```
gksu gedit /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-nvidia.conf
```

If your file is empty as mine was then open up the app "NVIDIA X Server Settings" from Unity.

Then go to the "X Server Display Configuration" section.

At the bottom of the screen click the button "Save to X Configuration". We don't want to actually save anything here, but click on the "Show Preview" button.

Scroll through until you see `Section "Device"` and the following `EndSection`. Highlight and copy the entire section. Mine looked like this:

```
Section "Device"
   Identifier     "Device0"
   Driver         "nvidia"
   VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
   BoardName      "NVS 5400M"
EndSection
```

Paste this into the /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-nvidia.conf file opened before.

Now paste the following line just before the `EndSection`

```
Option        "RegistryDwords" "EnableBrightnessControl=1"
```

It should look like this:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "NVS 5400M"
    Option         "RegistryDwords" "EnableBrightnessControl=1"
EndSection
```

Now save and close /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-nvidia.conf and reboot. My brightness control now works. Got the idea from [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/458256/ubuntu-14-04-brightness-issue-with-nvidia-quadro) related post.

Comment: Works perfectly on my Lenovo W520. Thanks for this clear description!

Comment: Nice and easy solution if using NVIdia drivers. Used on Lenovo W510, work perfectly.

Comment: Works fine with my Thinkpad T430 and Discrete Graphics enabled in BIOS.

Comment: There is a trick, Nvidia X Server Settings have no data in the preview and somehow does not save to a visible file. BUT I saved the configuration twice and it created a backup file. From that file I was able to pick up the ```Section "Device``` part.

Comment: worked perfectly on W520 running 18.04.1 LTS too with minor change of my file name which is 10- `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-nvidia.conf` i recommend when you look for the nvidia file to use * in the number in case the order number is different at your laptop

Answer (score 1):

Is it that the brightness control doesn't persist or is it that modifying it has no effect?

I have had issues where changing brightness control didn't persist across reboots. I have a Dell XPS L502X with an integrated Intel and a GeForce GT 540M graphics card. I use xbacklight to overcome the problem. Install the package with

```
sudo apt-get install xbacklight
```

and use the following command to set the brightness, say

```
xbacklight -set 20%
```

If you want to automate this, you can add this to "Startup Applications", so that every time your computer starts, the brightness would be set to 20%.

Comment: Does not help unfortunately :(

Answer (score 0):

Run `sudo nvidia-xconfig` to generate the `xorg.conf` file.

I am having the same issue, however even after setting the DWord in xorg.conf the brightness is not changing.