# Brightness key not working Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, lenovo, screen, brightness

I've just installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my Lenovo Z400 notebook and everything was working.
Today I tried to change the brightness of the screen and it gets dark and I can't go back.
Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Comment: related https://askubuntu.com/questions/468277/screen-brightness-isnt-taking-effect-on-a-lenovo-z570

Answer (score 16):

I faced the same problem before on my laptop ***Lenovo z500 ideapad*** after  searching i found this solution :

1. open terminal
2. `sudo nano "/etc/default/grub"`
3. append `acpi_backlight=vendor` to the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` line:

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"
   ```
4. save and close `nano` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, then confirm saving changes)
5. `sudo update-grub`
6. restart

If nothing changes , you can check the solutions of this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/468277/screen-brightness-isnt-taking-effect-on-a-lenovo-z570).

Comment: This does not work for ThinkPad P50 on 17.10.

Comment: this did not work. (Lenovo Ideapad).