# Screen Brightness not binded to Multimedia keys properly

Tags: laptop, screen, brightness

After I installed Ubuntu 16.04, I found that the brightness of display was set to brightest possible and I wasn't able to change it. Then I installed Brightness Controller and it worked. Then from some other answer, I binded the 'brightness multimedia key' from my keyboard to control the brightness. 
But now when I reduce to least bright, the display turns black. How do I set it correct ??

Comment: what's controller you install !!

Comment: check my answer here to change brightness !! http://askubuntu.com/a/770100/464430

Comment: http://lordamit.github.io/Brightness/
this one.

Comment: this application not change brightness it change color

Comment: i tried <append "acpi_backlight=vendor" to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT> but still when I reduce to the least bright, it gets black, like it is turned off.

Comment: how you reduce it open ? **all settings -> brightness & lock** and change it or **fn+brightness key**

Comment: Would you like a scripting solution ? Basically , it's going to be a program that wont allow brightness to go past the specific minimum. How's that ?

Comment: oh yes, sure I do.

Comment: that's what I want, like fixing the lowest to something small rather than 0.

Comment: @MohamedSlama now I can use both, but I generally prefer fn+brightness key.

Comment: if the problem fixed attach an answer and mark as solver

Comment: its not fixed yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated my system to recently released Ubuntu 16.10, and it solved this problem. The multimedia key for Brightness control is working properly.
But the min value of Brightness leads to black screen.

Comment: Nice that you were able to find a solution for your problem. Don't forget that you can (and should) accept your own answer to mark the question as solved. However, if it does not really solve your problem or leads to a different problem than the one described in your original question, you might consider posting a new question about that, adding a link to this post as reference on what happened before.