# Can’t change brightness of Thinkpad X1 Extreme 4K in Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: brightness

I went to Nvidia website to update the driver for Nvidia 1050 Ti. I can use the function keys to change the volume but I cannot use those F5 and F6 keys to change the brightness. Could you please let me know how to fix it?

Comment: Based on your [later question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1086142/301745), it seems like you found a solution [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/769006/301745), though it doesn't work properly. (Just mentioning this for anyone else who reads this.)

Comment: There is a partial solution there but it does not fully work properly in this case. Changing Discrete and Hybrid in BIOS also break it. https://askubuntu.com/questions/769006/brightness-key-not-working-ubuntu-16-04-lts

Comment: For unknown reason, this method no longer works.

Comment: Hello @lovedrinking, I have the same issue and so far did not find a solution. I would like to continue using Ubuntu if possible.How did this end up for you? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

As I was in the same situation, I found compromise solution that I want to describe.

First, in order to install Ubuntu 18.01, it was first necessary to change in the BIOS the video setting from "Hybrid graphics" to "Discrete graphics" (which bricked the machine because of a bug in the BIOS, but the machine got replaced after a month, but this is another story).

Finally, with Discrete mode On, I could install Ubuntu 18.01. But then this brightness stuff didn't work. When going back into BIOS and switching to Hybrid mode, then the graphics wouldn't work.

So, I installed the proprietary (non opensource) Nvidia drivers through the "Software & Updates" Program. Rebooted, still no possibility to adjust brightness.

But now, with the proprietary Nvidia driver I can switch the BIOS setting to Hybrid mode again, and then the brightness controls work!