# Unable to change brightness of Thinkpad X1 Extreme 4K using function keys

Tags: brightness, thinkpad

I disabled Secure Boot in BIOS and reinstalled Ubuntu 18.10. I followed the steps described in the following link to modify the grub. However, after executing sudo update-grub and rebooted the system, I still cannot change the brightness using the function keys.

[Brightness key not working Ubuntu 16.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/769006/brightness-key-not-working-ubuntu-16-04-lts/1086129?noredirect=1#comment1786600_1086129)

Comment: @lovedrinking See thinkwiki for possible solutions - [special keys](https://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/How_to_get_special_keys_to_work) and [LCD Brightness](https://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/LCD_Brightness). It should work if correctly set-up. But I think that it should work out-the-box. ThinkPads are linux-friendly.

Comment: How come? Is there a way to make the brightness keys  work? I installed the latest Nvidia driver but it doesn’t help.

Comment: Any resolution? I've seen people mention that it works on PopOS!, which is an Ubuntu derivative, so I wonder why it doesn't work on Ubuntu.

Comment: I installed Ubuntu 18.10 and then installed the automatically suggested nVidia proprietary drivers using `ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` in recovery mode, and my brightness keys work fine. I also switched to LightDM instead of GDM3 but that was more because locking the screen was not working properly with GDM3, I think the brightness keys still worked.

I also have the 4k screen.

Comment: with ubuntu 18.04 on the X1 extreme I installd `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` as mentioned by @Ibrahim and rebooted.  (I noticed it was a little dim) The screen got brighter, but the function keys for brightness still don't work.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've figured it out for me, at least with ubuntu 18.04 as of 2/11/2019.

1. Install ubuntu nvidia drivers:

   ```
   # use auto-install (as mentioned by @Ibrahim)
   sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
   ```
2. Edit the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` entry in the `/etc/default/grub` to the following:

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nvidia.NVreg_EnableBacklightHandler=1"
   ```
3. Update grub configuration after edit and save:

   ```
   sudo update-grub
   ```
4. Reboot:

   ```
   sudo reboot
   ```

Comment: ```sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall``` and a reboot worked for me after upgrade 20.04 to 22.04 with Lenovo Thinkpad X1 Extreme