# Screen will not change brightness (Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS) [UPDATED INFO]

Tags: 18.04, lenovo, brightness, amd-ryzen

I am restating my question as posed on [my previous post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1211400/screen-will-not-change-brightness-ubuntu-18-04-4-lts?noredirect=1#comment2035873_1211400).
I cannot change the brightness on my machine.

I have a Lenovo Ideapad (330S-15ARR - Type 81FB) running Ubuntu 18.04.4 with an AMD  Ryzen 5 2500u with radeon vega mobile gfx × 8.

When running

> ls /sys/class/backlight

the result is

```
acpi_video0
```

Has anyone else had a similar issue and found a resolution?

Apologies about my previous question not being detailed enough, I have been absent from tech for some time now.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Brightness key not working Ubuntu 16.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/769006/brightness-key-not-working-ubuntu-16-04-lts)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Screen will not change brightness (Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1211400/screen-will-not-change-brightness-ubuntu-18-04-4-lts)

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues with a toshiba laptop. This may help:

**Make a backup copy of any files that are changed.**

Edit the file `/etc/default/grub`.

Find the line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`

Add `acpi_backlight=vendor` so the line is now:

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"`

After file is edited and saved run the command:

`sudo update-grub`

Reboot to see if changes have helped.

If there seems to be no change then here are some similar solutions than may lead to an answer for you.

[Cannot change backlight brightness Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/476664/cannot-change-backlight-brightness-ubuntu-14-04)

[Function Keys Do Not work (Brightness & Sound) Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866437/function-keys-do-not-work-brightness-sound-ubuntu-16-04)

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this is still relevant for the questioner but maybe some people (like me) will encounter the same problem, so here is what helped on my system:

Update the kernel to a higher version(e.g. 5.8.17 by using a tool like https://github.com/pimlie/ubuntu-mainline-kernel.sh)

Trying to change the value GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT= to a variety of different alternatives almost had no effect at all for me.