# Brightness controls disabled upon unplugging HDMI

Tags: 14.04, screen

I'm running Ubuntu Gnome 14.04 on a Thinkpad X1 Carbon. When I unplug the HDMI cable, my brightness comes down to zero, and I can't increase it again.
With <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F9</kbd> as I normally would.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced the same problem before on my laptop ***Lenovo z500 ideapad*** after  searching i found this solution :

```
 1. open terminal 
 2. sudo gedit "/etc/default/grub"
 3. append "acpi_backlight=vendor" to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT
 4. GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"
 5. save and close gedit
 6. sudo update-grub
 7. restart
```

If nothing changes , you can check the solutions of this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/468277/screen-brightness-isnt-taking-effect-on-a-lenovo-z570).

Comment: Hahaa, no I can't adjust brightness at all. I'm gonna try to revert back.

Comment: for advice if not working for all answers in the attached url specially SPRBRN answer upgrade to 16.04 i have had the same issue on linux mint , but on ubuntu was working fine @Costa