# Brightness control does not work in Ubuntu 14:04

Tags: 14.04, brightness, inspiron

I have a "Inspirion 15r SE 7520" and the Brightness control doesn't work. Using `amd` driver, I have already added:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"
```

to the grub config file but with this line, my Ubuntu doesn't start.

What I have to do?

Using AMD RADEON HD7700M SERIES and my notebook have Hybrid graphics.

Comment: I had a similar problem, answers from this questions helped me http://askubuntu.com/questions/450131/problem-with-adjusting-brightness-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: did not work xPP

Comment: @user284626 After editing grub config file,before reboot, have you run: `sudo update-grub`? this might help.

Comment: yes i did it xP but after this my ubuntu doesnt start any more

Comment: I found this temporary solution : 

    echo 150 | sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness

But the `FN key` still doesn't working...

Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I have downloaded this for nvidia geforce
Adjust backlight of Compaq Armada laptops (E300, M500, M700)
Change LCD brightness on GeForce cards

and updated my grub file with

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash video.use_native_backlight=1"
```

I got it working.... :-)