# Issues on ASUS X550LC (after installing ubuntu)

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, bluetooth, brightness, asus

I've installed **ubuntu 14.04** on my **ASUS X550LC**. Here I've found some issue:

1. Bluetooth is not working.
2. Brightness is going 100% after every reboot.
3. Brightness and network controlling shortcut key is not working.
4. Network LED (which should be green when connected with internet) is not working.

To solve brightness issue I have tried first and second solution from  [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/450131/problem-with-adjusting-brightness-ubuntu-14-04) question, but that does not worked.

To solve bluetooth, I have tried Blueman from Software center, but that does not worked.

Output of `lsusb`

```
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 046d:c05a Logitech, Inc. M90/M100 Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 04f2:b40a Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 002 Device 013: ID 0fce:7172 Sony Ericsson Mobile Communications AB 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Output of `lspci -nn`

```
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller [8086:0a04] (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0a16] (rev 09)
00:03.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller [8086:0a0c] (rev 09)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0a03] (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP USB xHCI HC [8086:9c31] (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP HECI #0 [8086:9c3a] (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP HD Audio Controller [8086:9c20] (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP PCI Express Root Port 1 [8086:9c10] (rev e4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP PCI Express Root Port 3 [8086:9c14] (rev e4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP PCI Express Root Port 4 [8086:9c16] (rev e4)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP PCI Express Root Port 5 [8086:9c18] (rev e4)
00:1d.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP USB EHCI #1 [8086:9c26] (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP LPC Controller [8086:9c43] (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] [8086:9c03] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP SMBus Controller [8086:9c22] (rev 04)
00:1f.6 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP Thermal [8086:9c24] (rev 04)
02:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:5287] (rev 01)
02:00.1 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 12)
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe [1814:3290]
03:00.1 Bluetooth [0d11]: Ralink corp. RT3290 Bluetooth [1814:3298]
04:00.0 3D controller [0302]: NVIDIA Corporation GF117M [GeForce 610M/710M/820M / GT 620M/625M/630M/720M] [10de:1140] (rev a1)
```

Comment: how is bluetooth not working?  Does the bt indicator show up in the title bar?  Do you have a bluetooth mouse showing up in the battery indicator?  I do have problems from the battery indicator -- mouse works until it shows up.

Comment: No, bluetooth indicator isn't showing in the title bar. And when I turn bluetooth on from `System settings>Bluetooth` and hit the button (on/off) it shows bluetooth is on. But nothing happened. ANd I can't use any other option like Visibility(ON/OFF) and +/- option (that is for connecting or adding new devices).

Comment: Please open a terminal with Ctrl+Alt+t and paste your `lsusb` output by [editing](http://askubuntu.com/posts/512409/edit) your question.

Comment: P.-H. Lin, I've edited my question.

Comment: Hmmm... maybe you Bluetooth is connected to the PCI bus, could you please update it with `lspci -nn`?

Comment: @P.-H. Lin, Question updated.

Comment: You Bluetooth is **Ralink RT3290 [1814:3298]**, which is not supported, see [Ralink RT 3290 Bluetooth Problem on Ubuntu 14.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/453605/ralink-rt-3290-bluetooth-problem-on-ubuntu-14-04) for more information.

Comment: @ P.-H. Lin, thanks a lot. Now bluetooth icon is appeared in the indicator. But it is still not working :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17571/discussion-between-scotia--and-p-h-lin).

Comment: no solution!!!!

Comment: Have you tried booting Ubuntu Utopic Unicorn Beta live to see if that fixes your problems? If so, you should wait a week or two for Utopic. I know it fixes a lot of hardware bugs. And I mean a lot. It's like the main focus of the release, rather than getting new features. For this reason, many people are calling Utopic "the boring release".

Comment: No I haven't tried it.

Answer (score 0):

For the brightness issue please do the following.

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

find the line that has "GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT" and change it as following

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi="
```

save and close gedit
then issue the following command into the terminal

```
sudo update-grub
```