# Ubuntu 12.04 brightness control not working on HP 255

Tags: brightness

The brightness of my HP 255 is stuck on its brightest level and won't turn down even when I move the cursor back and forward. I tried some of the answers to this on my computer, and now the whole brightness control bar is missing. I'm new on Ubuntu, so can somebody please help me?

Comment: try this:http://askubuntu.com/a/503602/294611 OR http://itsfoss.com/fix-brightness-ubuntu-1310/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>).
2. Then type `sudo nano /etc/default/grub`. It will ask for your password. Type it in.
3. Around the 11th line, there will be something like: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`. Change it to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"`
4. Save the file by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> followed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>. Then run `sudo update-grub` in the terminal.
5. Reboot and see if backlight adjustment works. If not, undo the changes you did above, by invoking the text editor as in steps 1 and 2.

Hope it helps.

Works for Acer Aspire v3-571,Acer Aspire v3 571g,Hewlett Packard Bell EasyNote TS,Acer Aspire 4755G,Acer Aspire 5750-6866, Acer Aspire 5739, Lenovo T540p

Comment: Nope, it didn't work. Actually that's what I've tried in the first place and it made the whole brightness bar go missing.