# Birghtness control not working on Ubuntu 14.04 on MacBook Pro

Tags: 14.04, ati, brightness, macbook-pro

I have Ubuntu 14.04 on MacBook Pro and I cant alter the brightness from *System Settings* (no option there). My graphics card details are as follows.

```
$ lspci | grep VGA
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Venus XT [Radeon HD 8870M] (rev 83)
```

I have tried many solutions online but none worked for me. I dont wanna try some scary solutions as I have already damaged system settings once, leading me to OS re-install.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is has happened before with Ubuntu.  Try out a software dimmer: https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/brightness-controller/

Other questions that may help you: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/182856/screen-brightness-adjustment-not-working-in-ubuntu-14-04

In `/etc/default/grub` make sure you have a`cpi_backlight=vendor` in `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`.

Here is mine:

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"`
Then run `update-grub` and reboot.

Another question (with a ton of answers) [Make xconf configuration permanent](https://askubuntu.com/questions/450131/make-xconf-configuration-permanent/505079#505079)