# Brightness settings keep getting reset after reboot

Tags: amd-ryzen

My brightness settings do not survive reboots.

How can I make them persistent?

Specs:

- AMD Ryzen 7
- Lenovo Thinkpad x13
- GNOME 3.36.5
- Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Is that your question ? https://askubuntu.com/questions/3841/desktop-doesnt-remember-brightness-settings-after-a-reboot