# Brightness resets everytime I restart my laptop in Ubuntu

Tags: brightness

I have recently installed Ubuntu and I really love it, except for one thing, whenever I restart my laptop the brightness resets to maximum by default.
Just mentioning that I use AMD CPU with integrated graphics and not Intel, so the folder that I get when going to /sys/class/backlight is "amdgpu_bl0" and not "intel_backlight" or "acpi_video0"
Your help is appreciated.

Comment: See here whether anything of this helps: https://askubuntu.com/questions/3841/desktop-doesnt-remember-brightness-settings-after-a-reboot

Comment: Thanks for replying, sadly that either didn't help, or I didn't know how to do it properly.