# ubuntu 20.04 brightness reset to max on startup

Tags: boot, 20.04, laptop, brightness

I execute the following command to bring down the brightness

```
xrandr --output eDP-1-1 --brightness 0.60
```

But the brightness jumps back to max level whenever I restart my laptop. How do I set the default brightness to a certain value?

Comment: Check this methods: https://askubuntu.com/questions/3841/desktop-doesnt-remember-brightness-settings-after-a-reboot