# Screen brightness appears to be set to minimum, but my laptop screen is full bright

Tags: brightness

I have a problem in Ubuntu 21.10 with my laptop screen brightness. After restart my screen is set to maximum, but the settings shows something else.

[image: System Menu Image]

```
$ cat /sys/class/backlight/amdgpu_bl0/actual_brightness
```

Output: 255. Same as the max_brightness

What should I do to solve this problem? I use a Lenovo IdeaPad Gaming 3 15ARH05.

Comment: Many AMD graphics "misbehave" with the brightness control but usually moving it up and down corrects it.

Comment: Yes it does. But it is frustrating to change it every time you open your pc. I want at least to remember the last brightness setting. I've seen a post https://askubuntu.com/questions/3841/desktop-doesnt-remember-brightness-settings-after-a-reboot, but I can't find rc.local and the post is kinda old.